# "How can I use a github repo from a same account but different computers?"

Tags: git, github

I have two laptops.Now,when I used to work on one laptop,I save some files on a folder then for updating this folder to the other laptop I used to use a flash drive.But I learned git and github and I am having a plan to control a github repo from my both computers with the same account so I don't have to use a flash drive for file updating in two laptops.
But I am facing problem...Like I can sync from two computers properly...

I tried git init a folder1 in computer one. Then I pushed it to the github from computer one.
Now from computer 2 I want also to git it from same account.So I clone it to computer two then edit some stuffs,put commits then again push it to github from computer tow.Now again I comeback to computer one and type git log but those commits in computer two which I made does not show.Again I do some commits from computer one and try to push  folder1 to the repo but it does not let me to push it saying something about master or origin problem.

My overall objective was two use one github repo controlled and synced by two computer for a easy file and folder updating from both computer but I failed to do it.

Comment: Did you ever *pull*, as the message suggests?

Comment: Bro git is passing by my head like a sniper bullet

Comment: And it's unlikely to become clearer if you don't bother to read the output or search for the error messages.

Comment: Yeah getting things done now dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the edits from computer 2 onto computer 2 you need to first `fetch` those changes from the remote, and then `pull` them into your local repository on computer 1. If you are using the git bash, these are the commands you need to use.

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git pull origin master
```

In these commands, `origin` is the name of your github remote and `master` is the name of the branch you are currently tracking. These names can be changed, but these are the defaults which appear to be the names in your case.

Note, you will likely need to revert the new changes you made to computer 1. Git will have a hard time trying to merge the changes from computer 2 with the changes you made to computer 1 when you were trying to commit the second time.

Comment: `pull` is `fetch + merge`. If you've already run `fetch`, there's no need to run `pull`, `merge` should be enough. Or just run `pull` without fetching first, as it fetches on its own.